# No output given when displaying an array

Tags: c#

I have a "foreach" function in the code that's supposed to shift all objects by two elements. For some reason no output is given at the end. I have no idea what's the problem.

Here is the source code:

```cs
using System;

namespace testy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] alphabet = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "U", "W", "Y", "Z" };

            string[] lol = {"a", "b", "r", "f", "d", "q", "u"};
            int i = 0;
            int por = 0;
            string[] output = new string[lol.Length];
            while(lol.Length == i)
            {
                while(lol[i] == alphabet[por])
                {
                    por++;
                }
                output[i + 2] = alphabet[por];
                por = 0;
                i++;
            }
            foreach(string lol123 in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lol123);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(lol.Length == i)` is false (lol.Length == 7, but i==0), so it never enters the loop. Btw, try to use debugger to execute the programm step by step if there are any uncertainties about the code

Comment: How should the output look like ?

Comment: [Worth reading](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lol.Length` is *not* equal to `i`, which is `zero`. While loops don't do anything when their condition is `false` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
....
while(lol.Length == i){ ... }
```

Here, you are iterating while `lol` is 0 in length. Since `lol` is initialized to be 7 elements long, the whole loop is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Result of `while(lol.Length == i)` condition is `false` due to which while loop is not getting executed and the last foreach loop is iterating through `output` array which is initialized but having `null` values in each element.